# Complaints about ambient getters/setters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, babeljs

I have an open source library -- Firemodel -- which among other things uses ES classes and getters/setters within those classes. This has never been an issue but suddenly in my VueJS frontend code I'm using is complaining about EVERY instance of these getters/setters.

Here's an example of how the error presents:

[image]

As you can see from the red-squiggly line, when I open the `d.ts` file in **vs-code** it recognizes the error but in contrast when I go to the Firemodel repo and open up the same transpiled file there with **vs-code** there is no error.

Notably when I transpile with **Firemodel** I use **tsc** and get no errors. I have a consumer of **Firemodel**, which also uses **tsc** to transpile and it too has no problems with Firemodel's generated `*.d.ts` files. However, the VueJS project -- which uses the out-of-the-box settings for Vue CLI -- fails the build with these errors. It uses **Babel** for transpilation.

This is making me feel that maybe Babel is the real culprit but I'm not sure. Has anyone seen this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved by upgrading the local version of Typescript in the consuming app (aka, VueJS app) to 3.7.x (it had been on 3.5.x which is still the default for new project when you use `vue create ...` and choose the Typescript option).

> Note: I have no idea *why* this fixes it but I've tried on two project and they both appear to work. If someone knows *why* I would love to hear. Does Babel detect this and behave differently? Does the VueJS build system detect?